# I need to slice an Image into 8 equal parts as a triangle and show it using subplot

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Here is my code that I tried for the above question and I could only figure out the first part.

```
`im=imread('sam.jpg');     
[h,w]=size(im);
a1=0*im; %For First Part
imshow('bck.jpg');
for i1=1:1:uint16(h/2)
    for j1=1:1:i1
        temp1=im(i1,j1);
        a1(i1,j1)=temp1;
    end
end
subplot(2,4,1)
imshow(a1)`
```

After this I am not able to make other parts as the full black image is shown. Please help regarding this.

Example: original picture

[image: original picture]

First slice

[image: first slice]

Comment: Could you please post an image with a (mouse drawn) rough sketch of how you want to divide it? From your code and description it is not entirely clear.

Comment: https://ibb.co/d3uNvb -  This is my Original Image and https://ibb.co/cVCvgG - This is what I need. This is the first segment. I need such 8 segments and all the segment is to be shown using subplot.